# Discord Bot to Count How Many Times 'bruh' is Said

Tags: python, discord, bots, counter

So this is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import discord.utils
import os
import json

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  counters = load_counters()

  if "bruh" in message.content:
    counters["bruh"] += 1
    await message.channel.send(str(counters["bruh"]))
    save_counters(counters)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Message_Counter(client))

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

But every time I run it and test it with the bot in discord, it says that 'load_counters' is not defined. Also, I am using the website repl.it and have the token saved as a secret key. I have the counter for how many 'bruh's there are in a json file with the code:

```
{
    "bruh": 0,
}
```

Comment: Where is `load_counters()` defined?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the JSON?

Comment: The JSON code is at the bottom and I am confused by what it means by needing to define load_counters() as I believe it is supposed to be function.